# VAADIN: combo-box always opens up

Tags: combobox, vaadin, vaadin7

In Vaadin demo combo-box opens up only if there isn't enough space to open down. But in my case it opens always up.

How to fix it? (can it happens because of changes to style, that we made?)

```
public class LocationSelector extends CssLayout {
    public LocationSelector() {
        ComboBox locationBox = new ComboBox();
        locationBox.addItems("Long Beach, CA", "Washington, DC", "Other");
        locationBox.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
        locationBox.setNewItemsAllowed(false);
        locationBox.setInputPrompt("Select your city");
        locationBox.setStyleName("locationBox");
        locationBox.setPageLength(1000);
        this.addComponent(locationBox, "locationBox");
    }
}
```

UPD: link to screenshot: https://vaadin.com/documents/portlet_file_entry/10187/temp.png/157a29b7-2f35-4ef1-9a2e-02506a6ede5b

Comment: What's the idea bhind the `setPageLength(1000)`?

Comment: to avoid pagination, but problem not because of that, I had tested

Comment: I don't see a reason why it should always be open. Can you post a print screen please?

Comment: not open, but it should open down because in my case it opens always up.

I can't add image because of low reputation

Comment: Sorry, I don't see wat your problem is. When looking at http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-input/multiple-value/combo-box : The dropdown shows up as soon as you search for a value, once you select a value the drop down closes. What is behaving differently in your application?

Comment: UP is direction, not state, https://vaadin.com/documents/portlet_file_entry/10187/temp.png/157a29b7-2f35-4ef1-9a2e-02506a6ede5b

Comment: It seems that you have CSS issue.
What theme are you using?
Btw, you can try to place your component in HorizontalLayout intead of CssLayout

Comment: Any chance the css class "locationBox" modifying the normal behavior? Try removing this class and check if it opens down.

Comment: Have you tried the drop down alignment?